# Is it possible in PL/pgSQL to evaluate a string as an expression, not a statement?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have two database tables:

```
# \d table_1
      Table "public.table_1"
   Column   |  Type   | Modifiers
------------+---------+-----------
 id         | integer |
 value      | integer |
 date_one   | date    |
 date_two   | date    |
 date_three | date    |

# \d table_2
     Table "public.table_2"
   Column   |  Type   | Modifiers
------------+---------+-----------
 id         | integer |
 table_1_id | integer |
 selector   | text    |
```

The values in `table_2.selector` can be one of `one`, `two`, or `three`, and are used to select one of the date columns in `table_1`.

My first implementation used a `CASE`:

```
SELECT value
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = table_1.id
WHERE CASE table_2.selector
      WHEN 'one' THEN
        table_1.date_one
      WHEN 'two' THEN
        table_1.date_two
      WHEN 'three' THEN
        table_1.date_three
      ELSE
        table_1.date_one
      END BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

The values for `selector` are such that I could identify the column of interest as `eval(date_#{table_2.selector})`, *if* PL/pgSQL allows evaluation of strings as expressions.

The closest I've been able to find is `EXECUTE string`, which evaluates entire statements. Is there a way to evaluate *expressions*?

Comment: What you ask for is not possible, like [@klin explains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31361452/939860). If you are trying to make your query *faster*, there are several options. If so, provide your version of Postgres, cardinalities, *all* constraints (PK, UNIQUE, FK, ...) and answer this: are there more columns in `t2` or is that all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the plpgsql function you can dynamically create any expression. This does not apply, however, in the case you described. The query must be explicitly defined before it is executed, while the choice of the field occurs while the query is executed.

Your query is the best approach. You may try to use a function, but it will not bring any benefits as the essence of the issue will remain unchanged.